# Hypothesis testing for dependent sample which can be partitioned so independent

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let $X(t)$ be stochastic process and suppose $m(t) \in \{0, 1\}$ (deterministic). I've obtained a sample $X_t$ $n \geq t$ and want to test $E[X(t) : m(t) = 0] < E[X(t) : m(t) = 1]$.

Unfortunately, $X_t$ is not an independent sample. However, I know that I can partition $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ so that each subset is independent - I can perform a two-sample t-test on each partition. How can I perform my overall test? I looked at repeated testing with Fisher's method and Pearson's method but the alternative for these is (I think) that at least one of the separate alternative hypotheses holds, not that the result holds "overall".

**E.g:** $X_t$ is a Markov process, so I can partition my sample by $\{X_1, X_3, \ldots\}, \{X_2, X_4, \ldots\}$, which are independent.

Comment: If $X_t$ is Markov, how are you getting those subsets to be independent?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374265/does-markovian-property-imply-independence

Comment: That's about conditional independence. How does that establish independence of those two subsets?

Comment: I thought that the markov property implies $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_k$ when $k < n$. I am not claiming the sets are independent of each other, but that they are both independent.

Comment: I have not studied Markov chains and perhaps my example is no good. Still, I think the question is clear nonetheless?

Comment: If $X_{t}$ is dependent on $X_{t-1}$ for all $t$, it is dependent on the process at all prior times as well; what Markov says is that all the information about $X_{t}$ is in $X_{t-1}$, but not that there is none in $X_{t-j}$.

Comment: I see…… Thanks!